# VLC RTSP stream works with GUI but not in CLI

Tags: audio, streaming, vlc, rtsp

I'm trying to stream the input of the microphone of my USB Webcam (Logitech C170) on my Rpi with VLC. When I use the GUI, it works well. However, when I try it in CLI, the client is unable to connect.

I use this command to launch the server:

```
cvlc v4l2:// :sout=#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8080/} :sout-keep
```

And this one on the client:

```
cvlc rstp://192.168.1.12:8080/
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!